# Silverlight/WPF sets ellipse with hexadecimal colour

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I am trying to set a colour of an ellipse object in code behind. So far I'm doing it by using the SolidColorBrush method. Is there a way to insert the colour value in hexadecimal, like in CSS?

Here is a code that I am using:

```
ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
```

Comment: It's very strange you can't do this in Silverlight, considering most XAML uses hex strings for color.  Thus, they have the code, but they're not exposing it for the rest of us in a manner to use in code-behind (C#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a simple [color converter function](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/659) to solve this problem. The happy faces are really the number 8 and a parentheses, like this: 8).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this would work

```
ellipse.Fill = 
    new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF00DD"));
```

(Edit: It looks like this is WPF only. [Alex Golesh has a blog post here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/alex_golesh/archive/2008/04/16/colorconverter-in-silverlight-2.aspx) about his Silverlight ColorConverter)

Although I prefer the `Color.FromRgb` method

```
byte r = 255;
byte g = 0;
byte b = 221;
ellipse.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r,g,b));
```

Comment: What do I need to inherit to use the ColorConverter?

Comment: In WPF it's in System.Windows.Media, in Silverlight, well it's not. See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.aspx)

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

// Describes the brush's color using RGB values. 
// Each value has a range of 0-255.
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
myRgbRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course, you could also do something like this (using the hex numbers in the FromArgb function):

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();

// Describes the brush's color using RGB HEX values. 
// Each value has a range of 0-255. Use 0x for HEX numbers
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0xFF, 0xC0, 0xD0);
myRgbRectangle.Fill = mySolidColorBrush;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one, small, fast and useful:

```
public static Color ToColor(this uint argb)
{
    return Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & -16777216) >> 0x18),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 8),
                          (byte)(argb & 0xff));
}
```

Use in code:

```
SolidColorBrush scb  = new SolidColorBrush (0xFFABCDEF.ToColor());
```

Of course it is needed to use 0xFFFFFFFF (uint) notation instead of "#FFFFFFFF" (string), but I am sure it's no big deal.

Answer (score 1):

For using a hex value:

```
 your_contorl.Color = DirectCast(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D8E0A627"), Color)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, as it works for textbox.

```
var bc = new BrushConverter();
textRichTextBoxEditor.Foreground = (Brush)bc.ConvertFrom("#FF97315A");
```

Visit http://soulsolutions.com.au/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/617/Using-Hex-Colour-values-to-set-Foreground-in-WPF.aspx