# How to define TextBox input restrictions?

Tags: wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, mask, input-filtering

How can I restrict TextBox to accept only capital letters, or for example digits, or forbid to put any special character?

Sure it's a piece of cake to catch TextInput event and handle the text here, but is it the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I've done this in the past with an attached behavior, which can be used like this:

```
<TextBox b:Masking.Mask="^\p{Lu}*$"/>
```

The attached behavior code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Provides masking behavior for any <see cref="TextBox"/>.
/// </summary>
public static class Masking
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey _maskExpressionPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("MaskExpression",
        typeof(Regex),
        typeof(Masking),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Mask"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(Masking),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnMaskChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="MaskExpression"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskExpressionProperty = _maskExpressionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been set.
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetMask(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskProperty) as string;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be set.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mask">
    /// The mask to set, or <see langword="null"/> to remove any existing mask from <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </param>
    public static void SetMask(TextBox textBox, string mask)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask expression for the <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method can be used to retrieve the actual <see cref="Regex"/> instance created as a result of setting the mask on a <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask expression is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask expression as an instance of <see cref="Regex"/>, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been applied to <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static Regex GetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        } 

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskExpressionProperty) as Regex;
    }

    private static void SetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox, Regex regex)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(_maskExpressionPropertyKey, regex);
    }

    private static void OnMaskChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        var mask = e.NewValue as string;
        textBox.PreviewTextInput -= textBox_PreviewTextInput;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);

        if (mask == null)
        {
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskProperty);
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskExpressionProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
            SetMaskExpression(textBox, new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += textBox_PreviewTextInput;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, e.Text);

        if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        //pressing space doesn't raise PreviewTextInput - no idea why, but we need to handle
        //explicitly here
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, " ");

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, pastedText);

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private static string GetProposedText(TextBox textBox, string newText)
    {
        var text = textBox.Text;

        if (textBox.SelectionStart != -1)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
        }

        text = text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, newText);

        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say it was. I did write it to be much more flexible than you need. Feel free to just take the concept and simplify for your needs.

Comment: Very nice, Kent. A flexible and powerful solution to limiting entry in a TextBox. +1

Comment: elegance! wish I could give more than +1

Comment: @Agzam, the only difficult part is learning RegEx without getting eyeball pain... and copying & pasting...

Comment: This is incredibly powerful. I've seen whole 3rd party controls that don't handle this half as well.

Comment: @KentBoogaart How can I do this "<TextBox b:Masking.Mask="^\p{Lu}*$"/>" programatically?

Comment: @Andres: `Masking.SetMask(textBox, "^p{Lu}*$");`

Comment: @KentBoogaart, how in the heck did you figure out GetProposedText? That is magical.

Comment: The only code I've found that work 100% , thank you Kent .

Comment: Any way to add this to a ComboBox's text field?

Answer (score 46):

I've improved Kent Boogaart's answer by also handling the following actions that previously could cause the pattern to be violated:

- Backspace
- Selecting and dragging text in a way that can violate the pattern
- Cut command

For example, Kent Boogaart's answer allowed the user to enter "ac" by first entering "abc" and afterwards delete the "b" with the backspace which violates the following regex

```
^(a|ab|abc)$
```

Usage (unchanged):

`<TextBox b:Masking.Mask="^\p{Lu}*$"/>`

Mask class:

```
public static class Masking
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey _maskExpressionPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("MaskExpression",
            typeof(Regex),
            typeof(Masking),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Mask"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(Masking),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnMaskChanged));

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="MaskExpression"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskExpressionProperty = _maskExpressionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been set.
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetMask(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskProperty) as string;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be set.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mask">
    /// The mask to set, or <see langword="null"/> to remove any existing mask from <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </param>
    public static void SetMask(TextBox textBox, string mask)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask expression for the <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method can be used to retrieve the actual <see cref="Regex"/> instance created as a result of setting the mask on a <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask expression is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask expression as an instance of <see cref="Regex"/>, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been applied to <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static Regex GetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskExpressionProperty) as Regex;
    }

    private static void SetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox, Regex regex)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(_maskExpressionPropertyKey, regex);
    }

    private static void OnMaskChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        var mask = e.NewValue as string;
        textBox.PreviewTextInput -= textBox_PreviewTextInput;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
        DataObject.RemoveCopyingHandler(textBox, NoDragCopy);
        CommandManager.RemovePreviewExecutedHandler(textBox, NoCutting);


        if (mask == null)
        {
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskProperty);
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskExpressionProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
            SetMaskExpression(textBox, new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += textBox_PreviewTextInput;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
            DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(textBox, NoDragCopy);
            CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(textBox, NoCutting);
        }
    }

    private static void NoCutting(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private static void NoDragCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsDragDrop)
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, e.Text);

        if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string proposedText = null;

        //pressing space doesn't raise PreviewTextInput, reasons here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/446ec083-04c8-43f2-89dc-1e2521a31f6b?prof=required
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, " ");
        }
        // Same story with backspace
        else if(e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            proposedText = GetProposedTextBackspace(textBox);
        }

        if (proposedText != null && proposedText != string.Empty && !maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }

    }

    private static void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, pastedText);

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private static string GetProposedTextBackspace(TextBox textBox)
    {
        var text = GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(textBox);
        if (textBox.SelectionStart > 0 && textBox.SelectionLength == 0)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart-1, 1);
        }

        return text;
    }


    private static string GetProposedText(TextBox textBox, string newText)
    {
        var text = GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(textBox);
        text = text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, newText);

        return text;
    }

    private static string GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(TextBox textBox)
    {
        var text = textBox.Text;

        if (textBox.SelectionStart != -1)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: You improved the solution in 3 ways but reading its short description doesn't ring a bell. I think it has to do with copy pasting text in the TextBox but Kent's solution already blocked faulty text. Can you maybe explain what use cases the improvements prevent? Thank you

Comment: These improvements prevent the user from violating the regex rule. So for example, before these changes, you could use Backspace to make the rule illegal. So if the pattern was `^123$` you could type `123` and then delete `2` and it would let you. Now it doesn't. Same goes for the other improvements - Cutting text and dragging text around.

Comment: I can see what you mean now but only a copy paste action can get the user to the point where there is "123" in the textbox to begin with. Typing just the character "1" (or any other character) will be impossible as it doesn't validate "^123$". Using backspace on a *typed* in string will always respect the pattern as the previous input was already validated. Some users will definitely copy paste and your improvement will address this edge case which would have been a mystery for a while how it happened. Thanks

Comment: "Using backspace on a typed in string will always respect the pattern as the previous input was already validated."

That's only true if the cursor is in the end of the textbox. If the user moves it to the middle and backspaces then, you're going to have an issue.

Comment: That's a good thought and took me a while to construct a regex that had had this problem. The trick is to introduce *optionality* (leaving the anchoring as its required for validation the *whole* thing): ^a?(ab)?(abc)?$ With that regex the user can backspace on the b and leave ac which is invalid. Your improvement addresses this.

Comment: Ok, I mean, you **might** have an issue :)

Answer (score 14):

I changed VitalyB's code to support Color Themes. Instead of blocking user input if it doesn't meet the RegEx script, it just highlights the text box. The text box will be the theme default without interaction, and then defaults to a light green or red depending on the value after the input is set.  You can also set the fail and pass colors programatically with:

```
b:ColorMasking.PassColor = "Hexadecimal Value"
b:ColorMasking.FailColor = "Hexadecimal Value"
```

The class is below:

```
public class ColorMasking : DependencyObject
{
    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey _maskExpressionPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly("MaskExpression",
            typeof(Regex),
            typeof(ColorMasking),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata());

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="Mask"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PassColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PassColor",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ColorMasking),
            new PropertyMetadata("#99FF99"));

    public static void SetPassColor(DependencyObject obj, string passColor)
    {
        obj.SetValue(PassColorProperty, passColor);
    }

    public static string GetPassColor(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(PassColorProperty);
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty FailColorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FailColor",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ColorMasking),
            new PropertyMetadata("#FFCCFF"));

    public static void SetFailColor(DependencyObject obj, string failColor)
    {
        obj.SetValue(FailColorProperty, failColor);
    }

    public static string GetFailColor(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(FailColorProperty);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Mask",
            typeof(string),
            typeof(ColorMasking),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnMaskChanged));

    private static void OnPassColorChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        var color = e.NewValue as string;
        textBox.SetValue(PassColorProperty, color);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Identifies the <see cref="MaskExpression"/> dependency property.
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaskExpressionProperty = _maskExpressionPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been set.
    /// </returns>
    public static string GetMask(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskProperty) as string;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the mask for a given <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask is to be set.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="mask">
    /// The mask to set, or <see langword="null"/> to remove any existing mask from <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </param>
    public static void SetMask(TextBox textBox, string mask)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the mask expression for the <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// This method can be used to retrieve the actual <see cref="Regex"/> instance created as a result of setting the mask on a <see cref="TextBox"/>.
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="textBox">
    /// The <see cref="TextBox"/> whose mask expression is to be retrieved.
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// The mask expression as an instance of <see cref="Regex"/>, or <see langword="null"/> if no mask has been applied to <paramref name="textBox"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public static Regex GetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox)
    {
        if (textBox == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("textBox");
        }

        return textBox.GetValue(MaskExpressionProperty) as Regex;
    }

    private static void SetMaskExpression(TextBox textBox, Regex regex)
    {
        textBox.SetValue(_maskExpressionPropertyKey, regex);
    }

    private static void OnMaskChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = dependencyObject as TextBox;
        var mask = e.NewValue as string;
        textBox.PreviewTextInput -= textBox_PreviewTextInput;
        textBox.PreviewKeyDown -= textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
        DataObject.RemoveCopyingHandler(textBox, NoDragCopy);
        CommandManager.RemovePreviewExecutedHandler(textBox, NoCutting);

        if (mask == null)
        {
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskProperty);
            textBox.ClearValue(MaskExpressionProperty);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.SetValue(MaskProperty, mask);
            SetMaskExpression(textBox, new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
            textBox.PreviewTextInput += textBox_PreviewTextInput;
            textBox.PreviewKeyDown += textBox_PreviewKeyDown;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(textBox, Pasting);
            DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(textBox, NoDragCopy);
            CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(textBox, NoCutting);
        }
    }

    private static void NoCutting(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private static void NoDragCopy(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsDragDrop)
        {
            e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        string passHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(PassColorProperty);
        string failHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(FailColorProperty);
        Color passColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(passHex);
        Color failColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(failHex);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, e.Text);

        if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(failColor);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(passColor);
        }
    }

    private static void textBox_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        string passHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(PassColorProperty);
        string failHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(FailColorProperty);
        Color passColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(passHex);
        Color failColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(failHex);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        string proposedText = null;

        //pressing space doesn't raise PreviewTextInput, reasons here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/446ec083-04c8-43f2-89dc-1e2521a31f6b?prof=required
        if (e.Key == Key.Space)
        {
            proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, " ");
        }
        // Same story with backspace
        else if (e.Key == Key.Back)
        {
            proposedText = GetProposedTextBackspace(textBox);
        }

        if (proposedText != null && !maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
        {
            textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(failColor);
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(passColor);
        }

    }

    private static void Pasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox textBox = sender as TextBox;
        var maskExpression = GetMaskExpression(textBox);

        string passHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(PassColorProperty);
        string failHex = (string)textBox.GetValue(FailColorProperty);
        Color passColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(passHex);
        Color failColor = Extensions.ToColorFromHex(failHex);

        if (maskExpression == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            var pastedText = e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)) as string;
            var proposedText = GetProposedText(textBox, pastedText);

            if (!maskExpression.IsMatch(proposedText))
            {
                textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(failColor);
            }
            else
            {
                textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(passColor);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(failColor);
        }
    }

    private static string GetProposedTextBackspace(TextBox textBox)
    {
        var text = GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(textBox);
        if (textBox.SelectionStart > 0)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart - 1, 1);
        }

        return text;
    }


    private static string GetProposedText(TextBox textBox, string newText)
    {
        var text = GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(textBox);
        text = text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, newText);

        return text;
    }

    private static string GetTextWithSelectionRemoved(TextBox textBox)
    {
        var text = textBox.Text;

        if (textBox.SelectionStart != -1)
        {
            text = text.Remove(textBox.SelectionStart, textBox.SelectionLength);
        }
        return text;
    }
}
```

To run, the script requires a class written by Aaron C, explained here: [Silverlight/WPF sets ellipse with hexadecimal colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783384/silverlight-wpf-sets-ellipse-with-hexadecimal-colour) shown here: http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/659

The code is below in case the website is ever moved:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void SetFromHex(this Color c, string hex)
    {
        Color c1 = ToColorFromHex(hex);

        c.A = c1.A;
        c.R = c1.R;
        c.G = c1.G;
        c.B = c1.B;
    }

    public static Color ToColorFromHex(string hex)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(hex))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hex");
        }

        // remove any "#" characters
        while (hex.StartsWith("#"))
        {
            hex = hex.Substring(1);
        }

        int num = 0;
        // get the number out of the string
        if (!Int32.TryParse(hex, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, null, out num))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Color not in a recognized Hex format.");
        }

        int[] pieces = new int[4];
        if (hex.Length > 7)
        {
            pieces[0] = ((num >> 24) & 0x000000ff);
            pieces[1] = ((num >> 16) & 0x000000ff);
            pieces[2] = ((num >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
            pieces[3] = (num & 0x000000ff);
        }
        else if (hex.Length > 5)
        {
            pieces[0] = 255;
            pieces[1] = ((num >> 16) & 0x000000ff);
            pieces[2] = ((num >> 8) & 0x000000ff);
            pieces[3] = (num & 0x000000ff);
        }
        else if (hex.Length == 3)
        {
            pieces[0] = 255;
            pieces[1] = ((num >> 8) & 0x0000000f);
            pieces[1] += pieces[1] * 16;
            pieces[2] = ((num >> 4) & 0x000000f);
            pieces[2] += pieces[2] * 16;
            pieces[3] = (num & 0x000000f);
            pieces[3] += pieces[3] * 16;
        }
        return Color.FromArgb((byte)pieces[0], (byte)pieces[1], (byte)pieces[2], (byte)pieces[3]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
private void TextBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string txt = TextBox1.Text;
    if (txt != "")
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "[^0-9]", "");
        if (txt != TextBox1.Text)
        {
            TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to make it a custom property,but its a simple solution. I would appreciate if anybody would convert this to property just like Kent did.

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another version of the existing solutions here. It's a Behavior simulating a "TextChanging" event providing the old text, the new text and a flag to cancel the change. This way we can implement whatever filter we want.

I got rid of the "PreviewKeyDown" handler used only for the space character. TextBox seems to manage everything with routed commands and "Space" does have its own commmand, though it's not public. I also added support for additionals keyboard shortcuts like "Ctrl+Backspace" (delete previous word).

```
public class TextChangingBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public event EventHandler<TextChangingEventArgs> TextChanging;

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
        CommandManager.AddPreviewExecutedHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPreviewExecutedHandler);
        DataObject.AddCopyingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnCopying);
        DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPasting);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();

        AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= OnPreviewTextInput;
        CommandManager.RemovePreviewExecutedHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPreviewExecutedHandler);
        DataObject.RemoveCopyingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnCopying);
        DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPasting);
    }

    #region Text

    private enum CharCategory
    {
        LetterOrDigit,
        Whitespace,
        Other
    }

    private CharCategory GetCharCategory(char c)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            return CharCategory.LetterOrDigit;
        else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            return CharCategory.Whitespace;
        else
            return CharCategory.Other;
    }

    private string GetText(string input = null)
    {
        var box = AssociatedObject;
        var text = box.Text ?? string.Empty;
        if (input != null)
        {
            // Delete selection
            var deleteCount = box.SelectionLength;
            if (deleteCount > 0)
                text = text.Remove(box.SelectionStart, deleteCount);
            // Insert input
            if (input.Length > 0)
                text = text.Insert(box.CaretIndex, input);
        }
        return text;
    }

    #endregion

    private void OnPreviewExecutedHandler(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var box = AssociatedObject;
        var selectionExists = box.SelectionLength > 0;
        var caretIndex = box.CaretIndex;
        string newText = null;

        if (e.Command == ApplicationCommands.Cut)
        {
            if (selectionExists)
                newText = GetText(string.Empty);
        }
        else if (e.Command == EditingCommands.Backspace)
        {
            if (selectionExists)
                newText = GetText(string.Empty);
            else if (caretIndex > 0)
                newText = GetText().Remove(caretIndex - 1, 1);
        }
        else if (e.Command == EditingCommands.Delete)
        {
            if (selectionExists)
                newText = GetText(string.Empty);
            else
            {
                newText = GetText();
                if (caretIndex >= newText.Length)
                    newText = null;
                else
                    newText = newText.Remove(caretIndex, 1);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Command == EditingCommands.DeletePreviousWord)
        {
            if (selectionExists)
                newText = GetText(string.Empty);
            else if (caretIndex > 0)
            {
                newText = GetText();
                var startIndex = caretIndex;
                // Include whitespaces
                do
                    startIndex--;
                while (startIndex > 0 && char.IsWhiteSpace(newText[startIndex]));
                // Include the next block
                var currentCategory = GetCharCategory(newText[startIndex]);
                while (startIndex > 0 && GetCharCategory(newText[startIndex - 1]) == currentCategory)
                    startIndex--;

                newText = newText.Remove(startIndex, caretIndex - startIndex);
            }
        }
        else if (e.Command == EditingCommands.DeleteNextWord)
        {
            if (selectionExists)
                newText = GetText(string.Empty);
            else
            {
                newText = GetText();
                if (caretIndex >= newText.Length)
                    newText = null;
                else
                {
                    var endIndex = caretIndex + 1;
                    // Include the current block
                    var currentCategory = GetCharCategory(newText[caretIndex]);
                    while (endIndex < newText.Length && GetCharCategory(newText[endIndex]) == currentCategory)
                        endIndex++;
                    // Include whitespaces
                    while (endIndex < newText.Length && char.IsWhiteSpace(newText[endIndex]))
                        endIndex++;

                    newText = newText.Remove(caretIndex, endIndex - caretIndex);
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.Command is RoutedUICommand cmd && new[] { "Space", "ShiftSpace" }.Contains(cmd.Name))
        {
            newText = GetText(" ");
        }

        if (newText != null && OnProcessChange(newText))
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void OnCopying(object sender, DataObjectCopyingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsDragDrop)
        {
            if (OnProcessChange(GetText(string.Empty)))
                e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private void OnPasting(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(typeof(string)))
        {
            if (OnProcessChange(GetText((string)e.DataObject.GetData(typeof(string)))))
                e.CancelCommand();
        }
    }

    private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Text))
        {
            if (OnProcessChange(GetText(e.Text)))
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private bool OnProcessChange(string newValue)
    {
        var oldValue = GetText();

        if (string.Equals(oldValue, newValue, StringComparison.Ordinal))
            return false;
        else
        {
            var args = new TextChangingEventArgs(oldValue, newValue);
            OnTextChanging(args);
            return args.Cancel;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnTextChanging(TextChangingEventArgs e)
    {
        TextChanging?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}

public class TextChangingEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string OldValue { get; }

    public string NewValue { get; }

    public bool Cancel { get; set; }

    public TextChangingEventArgs(string oldValue, string newValue)
    {
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Just want to add that Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf nuget package is needed for this to work.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution is to use one of the "Masked TextBox" wpf implementation using the "MaskedTextProvider" class that is used by the "MaskedTextBox" from Winforms.

Two potential solutions are found here -> https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox and here -> http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/masked-textbox/