# Only allow special characters in Textbox when pressing keys on keyboard

Tags: .net, wpf, text

I need a textbox where the user only can work with uppercase characters. Also some special characters like - `_` and `<`.

I wonder if there could be a ways to catch the `PreviewKeyDown` or `KeyDown` Event to convert the pressed keys to `UpperCase`.

`MyTextBox1 > System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs > Key` is ReadOnly.

Any idea how that can be managed?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/wpf-textbox-how-to-define-some-restriction

Comment: a dup, but a different and simple answer...brillant!

Comment: no dublicate because just I searched on `KeyDown` (as idea) like the other question but only needed UpperCase and in this case I do not need to touch my huge way using `KeyDown` just WPF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do that, you can just use the [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property

```
<TextBox CharacterCasing="Upper" />
```

Other than that if you need a more general answer, look at my answer to [How do I get a TextBox to only accept numeric input in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268552/how-do-i-get-a-textbox-to-only-accept-numeric-input-in-wpf/1268648#1268648) here

Comment: What a great simple answer. I thought it is not too difficult but not thought that is that easy! Thanks for quick reply Ray!