# Format text box to accept only numbers and white spaces and plus sign

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am trying to make a `text-box` which will only accept numbers, white spaces and plus sign.

Currently I have done something like this in `KeyPressEvent` of the `textbox`

```
if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) &&!char.IsWhiteSpace(e.KeyChar))
    {
                e.Handled = true;
    }
```

I want to accept the `+` sign as well

**Update**

I did handle the `!char.IsSymbol(e.KeyChar)` but it will accept the `=` sign as well with the `+`

Any help!!!

Thanks

Comment: In what end-user facing technology?  Win Forms?  HTML?

Comment: and if someone tries to paste from the clipboard?

Comment: You should consider using the validating event.

Comment: Consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/how-to-define-textbox-input-restrictions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added

`var reg = new Regex(@"^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$");`

as regex

Answer (score 1):

For having "during input" control and validating control, you can make something like that.

But you'll have many things in your textbox (1+++   +2 34+), which doesn't mean a lot...

```
textBox.KeyDown += (sender, e) =>
                               {
                                   if (!(
                                       //"+
                                       e.KeyCode == Keys.Add || 
                                       //numeric
                                       (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) || 
                                       //space
                                       e.KeyCode == Keys.Space))
                                   {
                                       e.Handled = true;
                                   }
                               };
textBox.Validating += (sender, eventArgs) =>
                                  {
                                      var regex = new Regex(@"[^0-9\+ ]+");
                                      textBox.Text = regex.Replace(textBox.Text, string.Empty);
                                  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, actually I am trying to make this text box to accept phone numbers

Comment: then make a "true" regex in the Validating event, shouldn't be too hard

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking you could append

```
     && !e.KeyChar == '+'
```

to your criteria and it should work as far as keyboard input is concerned , but if the goal is to only allow numeric input the .net control library also contains a NumericUpDown control that can do the trick.

Comment: Numericupdown wont allow + or whitespace.

Comment: True, I read in the responses that the goal is a phone number. The maskedtextbox could do the trick for that, but it would restrict the format, so I don't suppose that would adequate either.

Comment: Phone numbers?  he said whitespace and +  I wish people would ask the question they really want answered...

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
if (!(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) 
    && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == '.'))
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I added the char.IsControl because it allows you to use Backspace in a typeerror case.