# Setting an accessible property on a textbox in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, dependency-properties

I have a texbox with added dependency properties which enables me to add a regex directly on the textbox and the textbox changes according if the regex has passed or failed. ([How to define TextBox input restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/how-to-define-textbox-input-restrictions) Nathan Tornquist post)

Now I want to add a property which I will update when the regex fails or not, so a boolean really.

I want that so that when I'm validating before adding new info into the database that all my new info passes their respective regex.

so basically I want to be able to do this

```
if(txtPostalCode.passRegex=true) Then
```

I have this so far added to the class

```
Public Shared ReadOnly PassRegexProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PassRegex", GetType(Boolean), GetType(ColorMasking), New PropertyMetadata(False))

    Public Shared Sub SetPassRegex(obj As DependencyObject, PassRegex As Boolean)
        obj.SetValue(PassRegexProperty, PassRegex)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetPassRegex(obj As DependencyObject) As Boolean
        Return DirectCast(obj.GetValue(PassRegexProperty), Boolean)
    End Function
```

The property shows when in the xaml bit of the code, but if I'm in a module or something, how can I access this value?

I believe maybe I'm not using the right way, but I've been looking alot on google, and can't seem to find a good answer to point me in the good direction with this.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code behind, you have to access it from the instance of your extended TextBox control, using the `GetValue` method:

```
bool passRegexValue = (bool)MyTextBox.GetValue(ColorMasking.PassRegexProperty);
```

(`GetValue` belongs to the underlying [DependencyObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589309) type.)

Comment: Well that was pretty simple actually. You are the best man! Thanks for the help.