# Showing Phone Number in specified format XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, string, xaml, textbox

I have a textbox in WPF.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" FontSize="30"></TextBox>
```

I need to enter only 10 digit phone numbers to it. Displaying format should be `xxx-xxx-xxxx`.
**Is it possible to handle this situation from XAML itself without the help of any code?.** If No How it is possible to do it with the help of code?

Comment: No, pure xaml is not possible. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1103822/1648849) answer.

Comment: [MaskedTextBox](https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox).

Comment: IMO it's not a duplicate because of XAML remark.

Comment: That question didn't provide me answer.

Comment: @AliasVarghese An `AttachedBehavior` would be your best option, as described in the [linked question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7572924/302677). It is some very useful helper code that I would put in my core library to use in other WPF projects as well whenever this functionality was needed. Alternatively, you could try to handle it your own way by using the `PreviewTextInput` event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="3" MaxLength="10(or your limit)" FontSize="30"></TextBox>
```

you can set the limit in xaml as well as in your view-model or code-behind file.

Answer (score -2):

use this function

```
   public string phoneformat(string phnumber)
   {
     String phone=phnumber;
     string countrycode = phone.Substring(0, 3); 
     string Areacode = phone.Substring(3, 3); 
     string number = phone.Substring(6,phone.Length); 
     phnumber="("+countrycode+")" +Areacode+"-" +number ;
     return phnumber;
   }
```