# How to correctly apply a regex to a textbox so unwanted characters cannot be typed using MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am having difficulty in getting the desired outcome when using a regex through WPF to limit what characters can be typed into a textbox. Currently I have a fairly standard Xaml textbox...

```
  <TextBox x:Name="txtRegistration" 
           Text="{Binding Registration,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
           IsEnabled="{Binding RegistrationIsEnabled}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
           Height="Auto"
           Width="Auto"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

...which is bound to this property in the viewmodel...

```
 private string _registration; 

 public string Registration
 {
        get { return _registration; }
        set
        {
            if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(value, "[^0-9]", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline))
            {

            }
            else
            {
                _registration = value;
            }

            RaisePropertyChanged("Registration");
        }
    }
```

I should point out that my viewmodel implements MVVMLight's version of ViewModelBase.

What I'm expecting to happen here:

1. if the user types a numeric character, the `regex.IsMatch` function won't find a conflicting character and therefore jump to the else statement where the field will be updated with the value as normal and passed back to the textbox.
2. if the user types a non-numeric character, the `regex.IsMatch` function will find a conflicting character and therefore not update the field with the new value. The textbox will be updated with the value that was held for the property before the user tried to enter a non numeric character, therefore effectively stopping them typing non numeric characters

When I breakpoint on the setter the process seems to work as I described above except the actual value shown in the textbox doesn't reflect this (e.g typing "123abc" into the textbox shows "123abc" instead of just "123")

I'm not entirely sure where the problem is here, so any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Also, I should point out I am not looking for a solution where the validation is done in the Xaml as I need it to be done in the view model for providing different options for the regex based on custom settings for different clients.

Thanks!

Comment: what about assigning a temp string to hold the original value and then setting it to _registration, then firing INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Personally, i would use implement IDataErrorInfo in your ViewModel.  you could test for whatever user client settings etc, and then you can provide feedback to the user as to WHY their entry is invalid etc.

Comment: What about trying an AttachedProperty like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1103822/302677), and binding the AttachedProperty value to the string regex in your model? That should prevent character entry, dynamic regex values, and is very reusable for any other cases that come up.