# WPF MaskedTextbox and "\" character

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, xaml

I'm using helper from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1103765/how-to-define-textbox-input-restrictions) article to create `MaskedTextbox` and I have problem with `\` character, if my mask contains this character

```
b:Masking.Mask="^[0-9]{1,4}\_$"
```

I get

```
'MaskExpression' property was registered as read-only and cannot be modified without an authorization key.
```

in `XAML` file, but I can start application, after starting I get:

```
Additional information: analyzing "^[0-9]{1,4}\_$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \_.
```

At:

```
SetMaskExpression(textBox, new Regex(mask, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace));
```

I have tried also using:

```
\\
&#92;
```

Instead `\` but it give this same result. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why escape `_`? Use `b:Masking.Mask="^[0-9]{1,4}_$"`. Or do you want to match a literal backslash? Then use `"^[0-9]{1,4}\\\\_$"` or `@"^[0-9]{1,4}\\_$"`. What is the valid input?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Error happens because your regex is invalid. If you want to include "\" character in regex - escape it: "^[0-9]{1,4}\\_$"

Comment: I thought that I need to use \ before _, my bad

Comment: Excuse me, could you please provide a sample string that you consider valid? Is `1_` valid or `1\_` string valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a `_` (underscore) is not considered a regex special metacharacter and should not be escaped.

```
b:Masking.Mask="^[0-9]{1,4}_$"
```

Note that only special regex metacharacters that have special meaning should be escaped.

See [*Character Escapes in the .NET Framework*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4edbef7e(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) reference:

> The characters included in the **Character or sequence** column (`. $ ^ { [ ( | ) * + ? \` - WS) are special regular expression language elements. To match them in a regular expression, they must be escaped or included in a [positive character group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z(v=vs.110).aspx). For example, the regular expression `\$\d+` or `[$]\d+` matches `"$1200"`.
>
> Characters other than those listed in the **Character or sequence** column have no special meaning in regular expressions; they match themselves.