# How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, hex

How can I get a color from a hexadecimal color code (e.g. `#FFDFD991`)?

I am reading a file and am getting a hexadecimal color code. I need to create the corresponding `System.Windows.Media.Color` instance for the hexadecimal color code. Is there an inbuilt method in the framework to do this?

Comment: string hex = "#FFFFFF";
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);

Comment: I know this is WPF related question but if anyone is using xamarin there is a method on the Color class: `Color.FromHex("#FFDFD991")`

Comment: @benscabbia WinForms and NET6, has the class, but not the method.

Answer (score 837, accepted):

I'm assuming that's an ARGB code... Are you referring to `System.Drawing.Color` or `System.Windows.Media.Color`? The latter is used in WPF for example. I haven't seen anyone mention it yet, so just in case you were looking for it:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

Comment: @Thorarin any help on how to get alpha value as I need to convert this value to be compatible with css rgba for web design.

Comment: @Yoda The first two digits (FF) are the alpha value. It's probably easier to use the `Color.FromArgb` method in this case though. If you use floating point alpha, you'd have to multiply by 255.

Comment: in case you have the RGB values -> Color.FromArgb(255,192,0)

Comment: string hex = "#FFFFFF";
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);

Comment: why not use color.FromArgb() instead?

Comment: Why not using FromArgb because it is simpler to copy past from Microsoft page.... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colors(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Works fine, though, you need to create an instance of ColorConverter before using its ConvertFromString method

Answer (score 625):

Assuming you mean the HTML type RGB codes (called Hex codes, such as #FFCC66), use the [ColorTranslator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator_members.aspx) class:

```
System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66");
```

If, however you are using an ARGB hex code, you can use the [ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533.aspx) class from the System.Windows.Media namespace:

```
Color col = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991") as Color;
//or      = (Color) ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFCC66") ;
```

Answer (score 146):

If you don't want to use the ColorTranslator, you can do it in easily:

```
string colorcode = "#FFFFFF00";
int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

The colorcode is just the hexadecimal representation of the ARGB value.

**EDIT**

If you need to use 4 values instead of a single integer, you can use this (combining several comments):

```
string colorcode = "#FFFFFF00";    
colorcode = colorcode.TrimStart('#');

Color col; // from System.Drawing or System.Windows.Media
if (colorcode.Length == 6)
    col = Color.FromArgb(255, // hardcoded opaque
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(0,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(2,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(4,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
else // assuming length of 8
    col = Color.FromArgb(
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber),
                int.Parse(colorcode.Substring(6, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber));
```

**Note 1**: NumberStyles is in System.Globalization.
**Note 2**: please provide your own error checking (colorcode should be a hexadecimal value of either 6 or 8 characters)

Comment: Great solution for those using Visual C# Express since it only requires `System.Globalization`.

Comment: +1: very nice to use. Used it in VB.NET: clr = Color.FromArgb(Int32.Parse("FFFFFF00", Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber))

Comment: Color.FromArgb requires a, r, g, and b parameters, not an integer.

Comment: This is also useful if you are using the Compact Framework in which ColorTranslator is not available

Comment: On Windows Phone at least, Color.FromArgb takes 4 byte arguments, not an int.

Comment: @user1763532 - After `colorcode = colorcode.Replace("#", "")` simply use `int a = byte.parse(colorcode.Substring(0,2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);` and so on for r, g, and b. Don't forget to replace the first parameter of Substring - the index - with 2 for r, 4 for g and 6 for b.

Comment: @HansKesting, `FromArgb` takes 1 parameter in `System.Drawing.Color` and 4 paramteres in `System.Windows.Media.Color`

Comment: Note this works for a 4 byte (eg. #FFFFFFFF) HTML colour (inc alpha). If you try with a 3 byte (#FFFFFF) alpha will be 0 and your colour transparent. You can easilly insert alpha if the color code is less than 8/9 chars. Great for Compact Framework.

Comment: This also won't work for the short hand 3 or 4 digit color definitions.

Answer (score 44):

The three variants below give exactly the same color. The last one has the benefit of being highlighted in the Visual Studio 2010 IDE (maybe it's ReSharper that's doing it) with proper color.

```
var cc1 = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#479DEE");

var cc2 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0x479DEE);

var cc3 = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0x47, 0x9D, 0xEE);
```

Comment: None of these returns `System.Windows.Media.Color`.

Answer (score 41):

There is also this neat little extension method:

```
static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static Color ToColor(this uint argb)
    {
        return Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & -16777216)>> 0x18),      
                              (byte)((argb & 0xff0000)>> 0x10),   
                              (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 8),
                              (byte)(argb & 0xff));
    }
}
```

In use:

```
Color color = 0xFFDFD991.ToColor();
```

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, and a little late, but why do you use -16777216 for the alpha value?

Comment: Small variation consistently using hex: return Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & 0xff000000) >> 0x18), (byte)((argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10), (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 0x08), (byte)(argb & 0xff));

Comment: This code is faulty. I couldn't figure out why nothing was showing up and it turned out to be because this code doesn't convert hex to ``Color`` properly. I used the code from @too and that fixed it.

Comment: Here there is a previous version this answer in so: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/784852/2721611](http://stackoverflow.com/a/784852/2721611)

Comment: You can just do `& 0xFF` on the final downshifted value each time, instead of needing all those different values to `&` it with.

Comment: @Nyerguds Agreed. And then the shift values will be powers of 2.

Comment: Doesn't  `Color.FromArgb` have an overload that simply accepts an `Int32` though? I mean, `System.Drawing.Color` sure does.

Answer (score 17):

I needed to convert a HEX color code to a System.Drawing.Color, specifically a shade of Alice Blue as a background on a WPF form and found it took longer than expected to find the answer:

```
using System.Windows.Media;
```

--

```
System.Drawing.Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EFF3F7");
this.Background = new SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(myColor.A, myColor.R, myColor.G, myColor.B));
```

Answer (score 14):

```
    private Color FromHex(string hex)
    {
        if (hex.StartsWith("#"))
            hex = hex.Substring(1);

        if (hex.Length != 6) throw new Exception("Color not valid");

        return Color.FromArgb(
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
            int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));
    }
```

Comment: In UWP Color.FromArgb() requires 4 byte arguments. So it will look like:
return Color.FromArgb(255,
    byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
    byte.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber),
    byte.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber));

Answer (score 12):

You could use the following code:

```
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFDFD991");
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to do it with a Windows Store App, following by @Hans Kesting and @Jink answer:

```
    string colorcode = "#FFEEDDCC";
    int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    tData.DefaultData = Color.FromArgb((byte)((argb & -16777216) >> 0x18),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff0000) >> 0x10),
                          (byte)((argb & 0xff00) >> 8),
                          (byte)(argb & 0xff));
```

Answer (score 6):

in asp.net:

```
color_black = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString("#FF76B3");
```

Comment: `ColorConverter` is availabe in `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media`. Which one do you mean (both are unrelated to ASP.NET)?

Comment: `ColorConverter` in `System.Drawing` can be used in ASP.NET

Answer (score 4):

This post has become the goto for anyone trying to convert from a hex color code to a system color.  Therefore, I thought I'd add a comprehensive solution that deals with both 6 digit (RGB) and 8 digit (ARGB) hex values.

By default, according to Microsoft, when converting from an RGB to ARGB value

> The alpha value is implicitly 255 (fully opaque).

This means by adding FF to a 6 digit (RGB) hex color code it becomes an 8 digit ARGB hex color code.  Therefore, a simple method can be created that handles both ARGB and RGB hex's and converts them to the appropriate Color struct.

```
    public static System.Drawing.Color GetColorFromHexValue(string hex)
    {
        string cleanHex = hex.Replace("0x", "").TrimStart('#');

        if (cleanHex.Length == 6)
        {
            //Affix fully opaque alpha hex value of FF (225)
            cleanHex = "FF" + cleanHex;
        }

        int argb;

        if (Int32.TryParse(cleanHex, NumberStyles.HexNumber, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out argb))
        {
            return System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(argb);
        }

        //If method hasn't returned a color yet, then there's a problem
        throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Hex value. Hex must be either an ARGB (8 digits) or RGB (6 digits)");

    }
```

This was inspired by Hans Kesting's answer.

Answer (score 2):

For any Xamarin developers out there, you will need to

1. Specify the color type in order to prevent Cast exception from assuming you are talking about Xamarin.Forms.Color instead
2. Create an object of type ColorConverter

```
var conv = new System.Drawing.ColorConverter();
var color = (System.Drawing.Color)conv.ConvertFromString("#FF1D65AE");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see *[Silverlight/WPF sets ellipse with hexadecimal colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783384/silverlight-wpf-sets-ellipse-with-hexadecimal-colour/10378228#10378228)* for using a hex value:

```
your_contorl.Color = DirectCast(ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#D8E0A627"), Color)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(string) method which converts your string (hexadecimal) to the color.

Example: (This works with ARGB, like "#FF1E1E1E".

```
Control.Background = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#1E1E1E"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(myHashCode);
```

Comment: Glances over the conversion from hex string to `int`?

Comment: Originally the question was asked as "How to get a color from a hash code" which created a lot of confusion in here. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

WPF:

```
using System.Windows.Media;

//hex to color
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#7AFF7A7A");

//color to hex
string hexcolor = color.ToString();
```

Comment: Actually, there is no hex but `Color [Indigo]`

Answer (score 0):

I used ColorDialog in my project. ColorDialog sometimess return "Red","Fhushia" and sometimes return "fff000". I solved this problem like this maybe help someone.

```
        SolidBrush guideLineColor;
        if (inputColor.Any(c => char.IsDigit(c)))
        {
            string colorcode = inputColor;
            int argbInputColor = Int32.Parse(colorcode.Replace("#", ""), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
             guideLineColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(argbInputColor));

        }
        else
        {
            Color col = Color.FromName(inputColor);
             guideLineColor = new SolidBrush(col);
        }
```

InputColor is the return value from ColorDialog.

Thanks everyone for answer this question.It's big help to me.

Answer (score 0):

There are many answers here already.

In short I support those that propose to use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator`.

I get that some people want to avoid `System.Windows.Media` so there is the other solution, and since you want to have a `System.Drawing.Color` you should have a reference to `System.Drawing` already in your project.

So in short: **Use the Framework** if you can.

## A more complete native solution

So, if for some reason you want to avoid `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator` and create your own implementation, you should at least make it respect the [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/)

So this is a solution that does `#RGB` and `#RGBA` shorthand - and extended color definition

```
    public static Color ParseHtmlColor(string htmlColor) => Color.FromArgb(HtmlColorToArgb(htmlColor));

    public static int HtmlColorToArgb(string htmlColor, bool requireHexSpecified = false, int defaultAlpha = 0xFF)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlColor))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(htmlColor));
        }

        if (!htmlColor.StartsWith("#") && requireHexSpecified)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Provided parameter '{htmlColor}' is not valid");
        }

        htmlColor = htmlColor.TrimStart('#');
        

        // int[] symbols 
        var symbolCount = htmlColor.Length;
        var value = int.Parse(htmlColor, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        switch (symbolCount)
        {
            case 3: // RGB short hand
            {
                return defaultAlpha << 24
                    | (value & 0xF)
                    | (value & 0xF) << 4
                    | (value & 0xF0) << 4
                    | (value & 0xF0) << 8
                    | (value & 0xF00) << 8
                    | (value & 0xF00) << 12
                    ;
            }
            case 4: // RGBA short hand
            {
                // Inline alpha swap
                return   (value & 0xF) << 24
                       | (value & 0xF) << 28
                       | (value & 0xF0) >> 4
                       | (value & 0xF0) 
                       | (value & 0xF00) 
                       | (value & 0xF00) << 4
                       | (value & 0xF000) << 4
                       | (value & 0xF000) << 8
                       ;
            }
            case 6: // RGB complete definition
            {
                return defaultAlpha << 24 | value;   
            }
            case 8: // RGBA complete definition
            {
                // Alpha swap
                return (value & 0xFF) << 24 | (value >> 8);
            }
            default:
                throw new FormatException("Invalid HTML Color");
        }
    }
```

If you for some reason don't want to use `System.Globalization` I'm sure you'll find a code snipped for parsing hex symbols.

## Tests

```
    public static void TestColors()
    {
        foreach (var testCase in TestCases) TestColor(testCase);
    }

    static string[] TestCases = new string[] { 
        "111",
        "FFF", 
        "17A",
        "F52",
        "444F",
        "2348",
        "4320",
        "121212",
        "808080",
        "FFFFFF",
        "A0E0C0",
        "0A070B",
        "FFFFFFFF",
        "808080FF",
        "40807710"
    };

    public static void TestColor(string htmlColor)
    {
        Console.Write($" {htmlColor} -> ");
        var color = ParseHtmlColor(htmlColor);
        Console.WriteLine("0x" + color.ToArgb().ToString("X"));
    }
```

P.S.:
Feel free to remove the paramters, they only intend to show how you could tweak the function to handle format errors and defaults.

P.P.S.:
The error messages are not very descriptive at the moment

Answer (score 0):

- XNA / Monogame (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color).
- Works for 6 or 8 (with alpha) character hexadecimal strings
- Probably better alternatives (bit masking/shifting) out there.

```
    using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
    using System.Globalization;
    
    public static class ColorBuilder
    {
        public static Color FromHex(string color)
        {
            var hex = color.Replace("#", string.Empty);
            var h = NumberStyles.HexNumber;

            var r = int.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), h);
            var g = int.Parse(hex.Substring(2, 2), h);
            var b = int.Parse(hex.Substring(4, 2), h);
            var a = 255;

            if (hex.Length == 8)
            {
                a = int.Parse(hex.Substring(6, 2), h);
            }
 
            return new Color(r, g, b, a);
        }
    }
    
    //create a blue color
    var color = ColorBuilder.FromHex("#2733C5"); //or ColorBuilder.FromHex("2733C5");
    
    //create a blue color with 50% alpha
    var colorTrans = ColorBuilder.FromHex("#2733C580");
```

Answer (score -2):

If you mean HashCode as in `.GetHashCode()`, I'm afraid you can't go back. Hash functions are not bi-directional, you can go 'forward' only, not back.

Follow Oded's suggestion if you need to get the color based on the hexadecimal value of the color.

Comment: @Wim Thanks for helping the OP clarify the question. I would say this answer is no longer needed, and recommend deleting it.