# Hexadecimal color code convertor

Tags: c#

Is it possible to convert Hexadecimal color code to string color value .
For instance if i give a hex color value as "#FFFFFF" it should return value as "White"

```
string hextostring(string color)
{
//some code//
return string ;
}
```

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name

Comment: See also in the "Related" section to the right, such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/2109756/121309

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net Does this post answer your question? I hope so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which version of .NET you're using, you should be able to achieve this by combining call of

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.fromhtml.aspx

and

```
ColorTranslator.ToKnownColor
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.toknowncolor.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
using System.Windows.Media;

Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFF");
```

For more details please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)