# Getting the color name from the ARGB and/or hexadecimal color palette

Tags: c#, colors, implicit-conversion, hex

I need to get the corresponding color name based on the color's hexadecimal palette code.

I tried:

```
 brush = (new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(dialog.Color.A, dialog.Color.R, dialog.Color.G, dialog.Color.B)));

 TheColor = Convert.ToString(brush);  //here i get the hexadecimal only
```

eg. Red ,cyan,blue things like that.

Comment: what if that hex value does not have any kind of name? How would you define *RED*? Your definition of red could be very different from mine.

Comment: this may help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net?rq=1

Comment: You can make millions of colors with RGB, there's no way the computer knows what you call every color.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7791803/122005) may also be of help.

Answer (score 4):

In .NET there is the concept of a "known color".

```
public string ColorName(Color toCheck)
{
    string result = "";
    foreach (KnownColor known in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    {
            Color c = Color.FromKnownColor(kc);
            if (toCheck.ToArgb() == known.ToArgb())
            {
                result = known.Name;
            }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Obviously this cannot recognize any color that you know, only those that come predefined in the .NET framework.

Otherwise you'll have to write your own recognizer, which should be pretty easy to do, using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for instance, where the key would be the RGB value and the value would be the name.

Comment: some of this would be dependant on the source of the RGB values. I don't think these would tie up with, for example, the HTML definition of *"Aqua"*. Not criticising what is an interesting answer, just pointing out that *".Net colours"* will not match all definitions.