# Simpliest way to convert a Color as a string like #XXXXXX to System.Windows.Media.Brush

Tags: c#, colors, brush

I think that the title is clear !

What I have now is :

```
System.Drawing.Color uiui = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(myString);
var intColor = (uint)((uiui.A << 24) | (uiui.R << 16) | (uiui.G << 8) | (uiui.B << 0));
var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(uint.Parse(value));
var brush = new SolidColorBrush();
brush.Color = Color.FromArgb(bytes[3], bytes[2], bytes[1], bytes[0]);
```

1- myString is like #FFFFFF like I said in the title

2- This fails on the BitConverter.GetBytes line which surprises me cause I got the int representation on my Color !

3- Anyway, I know that COlor conversion are not that intuitive but I feel like I'm not doing it right...
Is that the good way ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Color from Hex color code using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net)

Comment: I always assumed that 0xFFFFFF could easily be translated to RGB by taking 16 bytes for each.  In other words 0XFF, 0XFF, and 0XFF.

Comment: the answer for that question was specific to WPF Media Color, I'd say it's not truly a duplicate

Comment: @AnthonyShaw the step from Media.Color to Media.SolidColorBrush is trivial, but added an answer anyway.

Comment: The difference was more about the string representation difference

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF010203");
//OR
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#010203");
//OR
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Red");

//and then:
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color);
```

It's pretty flexible as to what it accepts. Have a look at the [examples in XAML here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.aspx). You can pass any of those string formats in.

Note: These are all in `System.Windows.Media` (for WPF) not to be confused with `System.Drawing` (for WinForms)

Comment: Worked fine with this code for my example : var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF" + myString.Substring(1));

Comment: @GuillaumeSlashy you shouldn't have to do that, it's pretty smart. Just give it your string if it's #XXXXXX

Answer (score 2):

This is the helper class that I've used in the past

```
    public static Color HexStringToColor(string hexColor)
    {
        string hc = ExtractHexDigits(hexColor);
        if (hc.Length != 6)
        {
            // you can choose whether to throw an exception
            //throw new ArgumentException("hexColor is not exactly 6 digits.");
            return Color.Empty;
        }
        string r = hc.Substring(0, 2);
        string g = hc.Substring(2, 2);
        string b = hc.Substring(4, 2);
        Color color = Color.Empty;
        try
        {
            int ri = Int32.Parse(r, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            int gi = Int32.Parse(g, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            int bi = Int32.Parse(b, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            color = Color.FromArgb(ri, gi, bi);
        }
        catch
        {
            // you can choose whether to throw an exception
            //throw new ArgumentException("Conversion failed.");
            return Color.Empty;
        }
        return color;
    }
```

and an additional helper class

```
        public static string ExtractHexDigits(string input)
        {
            // remove any characters that are not digits (like #)
            var isHexDigit
                = new Regex("[abcdefABCDEF\\d]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            string newnum = "";
            foreach (char c in input)
            {
                if (isHexDigit.IsMatch(c.ToString()))
                {
                    newnum += c.ToString();
                }
            }
            return newnum;
        }
```

Comment: You should look up `ColorConverter`. There's one for WinForms and one for WPF.

Comment: that's pretty slick, wasn't aware that it existed. Thanks Ray!

Answer (score 0):

Just use ColorTranslator method:

```
ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#010203");
```