# Text to HTML Conversion

Tags: c#, html

What I am doing is Loading some Strings From database , I am doing that fine . I read it and Convert it to HTML ... kinda .. using this code :

```
    private string StripHTML(string source)
    {
        try
        {
            string result;

            // Remove HTML Development formatting
            // Replace line breaks with space
            // because browsers inserts space
            result = source.Replace("\r", " ");
            // Replace line breaks with space
            // because browsers inserts space
            result = result.Replace("\n", " ");
            // Remove step-formatting
            result = result.Replace("\t", string.Empty);
            // Remove repeating spaces because browsers ignore them
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                                                                  @"( )+", " ");

            // Remove the header (prepare first by clearing attributes)
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*head([^>])*>", "<head>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"(<( )*(/)( )*head( )*>)", "</head>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(<head>).*(</head>)", string.Empty,
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // remove all scripts (prepare first by clearing attributes)
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*script([^>])*>", "<script>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"(<( )*(/)( )*script( )*>)", "</script>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            //result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
            //         @"(<script>)([^(<script>\.</script>)])*(</script>)",
            //         string.Empty,
            //         System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"(<script>).*(</script>)", string.Empty,
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // remove all styles (prepare first by clearing attributes)
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*style([^>])*>", "<style>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"(<( )*(/)( )*style( )*>)", "</style>",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(<style>).*(</style>)", string.Empty,
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // insert tabs in spaces of <td> tags
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*td([^>])*>", "\t",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // insert line breaks in places of <BR> and <LI> tags



            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*br( )*>", "\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*li( )*>", "\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // insert line paragraphs (double line breaks) in place
            // if <P>, <DIV> and <TR> tags
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*div([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*tr([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<( )*p([^>])*>", "\r\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Remove remaining tags like <a>, links, images,
            // comments etc - anything that's enclosed inside < >
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"<[^>]*>", string.Empty,
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // replace special characters:
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @" ", " ",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&bull;", " * ",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&lsaquo;", "<",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&rsaquo;", ">",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&trade;", "(tm)",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&frasl;", "/",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&lt;", "<",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&gt;", ">",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&copy;", "(c)",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&reg;", "(r)",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // Remove all others. More can be added, see
            // http://hotwired.lycos.com/webmonkey/reference/special_characters/
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     @"&(.{2,6});", string.Empty,
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);




            // for testing
            //System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
            //       this.txtRegex.Text,string.Empty,
            //       System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // make line breaking consistent
            result = result.Replace("\n", "\r");

            // Remove extra line breaks and tabs:
            // replace over 2 breaks with 2 and over 4 tabs with 4.
            // Prepare first to remove any whitespaces in between
            // the escaped characters and remove redundant tabs in between line breaks
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\r)( )+(\r)", "\r\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\t)( )+(\t)", "\t\t",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\t)( )+(\r)", "\t\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\r)( )+(\t)", "\r\t",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // Remove redundant tabs
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\r)(\t)+(\r)", "\r\r",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // Remove multiple tabs following a line break with just one tab
            result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result,
                     "(\r)(\t)+", "\r\t",
                     System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            // Initial replacement target string for line breaks
            string breaks = "\r\r\r";
            // Initial replacement target string for tabs
            string tabs = "\t\t\t\t\t";
            for (int index = 0; index < result.Length; index++)
            {
                result = result.Replace(breaks, "\r\r");
                result = result.Replace(tabs, "\t\t\t\t");
                breaks = breaks + "\r";
                tabs = tabs + "\t";
            }

            // That's it.
            return result;
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error");
            return source;
        }
    }
```

the problem is , that some Strings contains HTML colors for example : <#D80000>StackOverFlow is a nice forum

What I want to do is to convert that HTML color to Color for the Text that Come after the HTML color , means "StackOverFlow is a nice forum Become with Red or what ever the Color is (color always X)

PS : It's on a tooltip ... what I 'am doing after Loading from Database :

```
  string XZ = StripHTML(XZSecond);
  Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { tp.SetToolTip(OMG[i], Name + "\r" + XZ.Replace("Text", "").Replace("Text", "")); }));
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using a templating engine like Razor for this?

Comment: What's an "HTML Color"? That doesn't look like valid HTML.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your question you simply want to conver the code #D80000 for example to a `Color`. Taken the answers in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net) might provide you the answer.

```
using System.Windows.Media;    
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

as answer from Thorarin

or

```
System.Drawing.Color col = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC66");
Color col = ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991") as Color;
```

as answer from Oded

Answer (score 0):

You can use of the [System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606533.aspx) Method to Attempts to convert a string to a Color.

Refer sample posts

[Simpliest way to convert a Color as a string like #XXXXXX to System.Windows.Media.Brush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178799/simpliest-way-to-convert-a-color-as-a-string-like-xxxxxx-to-system-windows-medi)

converting String to Html refer post

http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/converting-text-to-html

Look into it help more

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/