# Trouble getting color c#

Tags: c#, colors

I have this code:

```
        int converted = Convert.ToInt32(value);
        string hexValue = converted.ToString("X");
        Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + hexValue);
        return color;
```

That get strings like "12222222" and converts them to C# colors.
But I'm getting this string "255" and I don't know how to handle this. Can anyone shed some light on this strange number?

Thanks

Update
Forgot to mention: in a demo project his function works with value="255". In my project - doenst.

Comment: why do you think 255 is strange?

Comment: What is the `value`? What do you expect?

Comment: value is the string, "12222222" witch works, and "255" witch doesn't. Any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure that your both projects have same code?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
string hexValue = converted.ToString("X8");
```

that will ensure that there are 8 characters in the hexValue

Comment: or X6 if you want 6 characters, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert an **integer** (`int` or `Int32`) to a `Color` you can simply use:

```
 // value is an integer in this case
 Color color = Color.FromArgb(value);
```

No need to convert it to a hex string.

If you want to convert a **decimal** `String` to a `Color` just use:

```
 int value = Int32.Parse(decimalString);
 Color color = Color.FromArgb(value);
```

if you want to convert a **hexadecimal** `String` to a `Color`:

```
 int value = Int32.Parse(hexString, NumberStyles.HexNumber); // System.Globalization
 Color color = Color.FromArgb(value);
```

Comment: Color.FromArgb does not accept a string as a parameter, which it appears from the question that value is

Comment: Well updated answer to cover all bases... though the op still did not clarify what his `value` variable is

Answer (score 0):

There is a converter in the framework.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178799/simpliest-way-to-convert-a-color-as-a-string-like-xxxxxx-to-system-windows-medi):

[System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF010203");
```