# Creating SolidColorBrush from hex color value

Tags: wpf

I want to create SolidColorBrush from Hex value such as #ffaacc. How can I do this?

On MSDN, I got :

```
SolidColorBrush mySolidColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
mySolidColorBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 255);
```

So I wrote (considering my method receives color as `#ffaacc`):

```
Color.FromRgb(
  Convert.ToInt32(color.Substring(1, 2), 16), 
  Convert.ToInt32(color.Substring(3, 2), 16), 
  Convert.ToInt32(color.Substring(5, 2), 16));
```

But this gave error as

`The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Media.Color.FromRgb(byte, byte, byte)' has some invalid arguments`

Also 3 errors as: `Cannot convert int to byte.`

But then how MSDN example works?

Comment: So stupid that they don't allow the default #FFFFFF format.

Comment: None of these work for UWP

Answer (score 390, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
(SolidColorBrush)new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffaacc");
```

Answer (score 26):

I've been using:

```
new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ffaacc"));
```

Answer (score 17):

[How to get Color from Hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net)

This I think is what you are after, hope it answers your question.

To get your code to work use Convert.ToByte instead of Convert.ToInt...

```
string colour = "#ffaacc";

Color.FromRgb(
Convert.ToByte(colour.Substring(1,2),16),
Convert.ToByte(colour.Substring(3,2),16),
Convert.ToByte(colour.Substring(5,2),16));
```

Answer (score 11):

```
using System.Windows.Media;

byte R = Convert.ToByte(color.Substring(1, 2), 16);
byte G = Convert.ToByte(color.Substring(3, 2), 16);
byte B = Convert.ToByte(color.Substring(5, 2), 16);
SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(R, G, B));
//applying the brush to the background of the existing Button btn:
btn.Background = scb;
```

Comment: It worked for me as this:
`SolidColorBrush Iris = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#5D3FD3"));
modeButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button{ Name = "ModeButton", Content = "Click", Foreground = Brushes.White, Background = Iris };`

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to deal with the pain of the conversion every time simply create an extension method.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static SolidColorBrush ToBrush(this string HexColorString)
    {
        return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(HexColorString));
    }    
}
```

Then use like this: `BackColor = "#FFADD8E6".ToBrush()`

Alternately if you could provide a method to do the same thing.

```
public SolidColorBrush BrushFromHex(string hexColorString)
{
    return (SolidColorBrush)(new BrushConverter().ConvertFrom(hexColorString));
}

BackColor = BrushFromHex("#FFADD8E6");
```

Answer (score 2):

vb.net version

```
Me.Background = CType(New BrushConverter().ConvertFrom("#ffaacc"), SolidColorBrush)
```