# Brush from color code

Tags: .net, wpf, brush

How to create a brush from the color code?

`#FFFFE4C4` is an example of of what I call a color code.
e.g. what I would like to do is

```
Brush brush = new Brush(#FFFFE4C4);
```

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062376/creating-solidcolorbrush-from-hex-color-value)?

Comment: @Lynn thanks I did not think to search on the word hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First get a [color from the color code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net), the create a brush from that:

```
Brush brush = new SolidBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFE4C4"));
```

Comment: @Blam: Aha, it's the `System.Windows.Media` brush, not the `System.Drawing` brush... You can create it the exact same way from a color.

Comment: Thanks, I just did not have the namespace included