# How to convert color to code and viceversa

Tags: c#, colors, color-picker

I have colors like "FF7B2900" from a program.
I need to be able to convert this kind of color code to color and back.

So for example to convert this code to color i'm doing like this:

```
            string colorcode = "FF7B2900";
            int argb = Int32.Parse(colorcode, NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            Color clr = Color.FromArgb(argb);
```

The problem is when i try to convert color to string because i need to pick a color with color picker and get (string) the same type of code together with alpha "FF7B2900" not the simple html code "#7B2900"

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Color from Hex color code using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the exact same hex string back by doing `clr.ToArgb().ToString("x").ToUpper()`. clr.ToArgb() gets your int back and calling ToString("x") tells it to ouput a hexadecimal string representation of the int.

Comment: `ToString("X")` to have it straight in upper case.

Answer (score 0):

the FF at the beginning refers to alpha, of 255. You can always remove the # at the beginning, and prefix with FF... that'll give you the same color.

Comment: ok my problem is that i have also colors like this "57087B00" what should i do in this case

Comment: Add a # in front of them. :-) Web colors which are 8 digit - #AARRGGBB use ARGB, so it works nicely. When Alpha is FF, it can be omitted to give #RRGGBB. Hope this explanation helps.

Comment: The 59 from "57087B00" represents the alpha and i needed and the problem is to get code from color with alpha i need also the alpha code i cannot put # in front

Comment: in HTML, you are allowed to use #57087B00 ...it means a color of R=0x08, G=0x7B, B=0x00 and Alpha=0x57