# How to convert Hexadecimal #FFFFFF to System.Drawing.Color

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Color from Hex color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net)

I want to convert a string like `#FFFFFF` to `System.Drawing.Color`. How do you do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hex-color-code-using-net

Comment: Voting to reopen, the dup question deals with a different type of Color structure.

Answer (score 287, accepted):

```
string hex = "#FFFFFF";
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
```

Note: the hash is important!

Comment: What about in UWP, where there is no System.Drawing namespace?

Comment: @AdrianK use the answer from codeteq. It work for me from NetStandard 2.0

Comment: This worked for me: item.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex(line.s_BackGroundCol);

Answer (score 30):

You can do

```
var color =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFFFF");
```

Or this (you will need the `System.Windows.Media` namespace)

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFFFFF");
```

Comment: When I convert white, I get not the white color exactly.

Answer (score 13):

Remove the '#' and do

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse("#FFFFFF".Replace("#",""),
                         System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier));
```

Comment: There are options available which do no require the conversion to a numeric value, this is an unnecessary step. The OP states it's a string

Comment: The other solutions are converting the string into a numeric value too, they are just doing it internally. If this is a question of optimization, then performance testing would be required to see how `Color.FromArgb()` w/ `int.Parse()` compare to `ColorConvertor.ConvertFromString()` and `ColorTranslator.FromHtml()`.

Comment: Won't that have an alpha value of 0?