# Working with hexadecimal color codes

Tags: c#

I am working on a Web Api that returns JSON data. How do I return a converted Color from hex code as a string or whatever type that can be wired up in the front end to represent a color?, in other words, how can I return the color White from `#ffffff` hex code and assign it to a Model property so it can be returned as part of a JSON response?

Comment: What framework are you using? WinForm/WPF?

Comment: For WPF: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2109756/8446

Comment: For Winforms: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12155811/8446 (and those are already both duplicates).