# get a color name from hex in .Net core (without using System.Drawing.Color) C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

i am trying to fetch the color name from the hex for an application but system.Drawing.color is not available in .netcore can someone suggest an alternative solution any API?

I tried MagickImage lib , that rturns hex code from string but not vice versa

I want something like this : string ColorName = GetColorName("#8090A6");

Comment: There are few third party libraries in JavaScript and .Net.

Comment: Can you please suggest one in .net core , i have been stuck with this since long .

Comment: Check these links- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7791710/convert-hex-code-to-color-name, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224404/get-color-name-by-hex-or-rgb, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12155811/how-to-convert-hexadecimal-ffffff-to-system-drawing-color

Comment: It doesn't look like this is built into .NET Core. You can "easily" add something that does the same, but it seems you have to do it yourself.

Comment: What would you use in .NET Framework, can you add a code sample? I wonder if #8090A6 is a known color in System.Drawing.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your own `Colors`-`struct` or `class` aswell as a method that returns the corresponding name of a given hex-color. This could look like:

```
public struct Colors
{
    public const string AliceBlue = "#FFF0F8FF";
    public const string AntiqueWhite = "#FFFAEBD7";
    public const string Aqua = "#FF00FFFF";
    public const string Aquamarine = "#FF7FFFD4";
    public const string Azure = "#FFF0FFFF";
    public const string Beige = "#FFF5F5DC";
    public const string Bisque = "#FFFFE4C4";
    public const string Black = "#FF000000";
    public const string BlanchedAlmond = "#FFFFEBCD";
    public const string Blue = "#FF0000FF";
    public const string BlueViolet = "#FF8A2BE2";
    public const string Brown = "#FFA52A2A";
    public const string BurlyWood = "#FFDEB887";
    public const string CadetBlue = "#FF5F9EA0";
    public const string Chartreuse = "#FF7FFF00";
    public const string Chocolate = "#FFD2691E";
    public const string Coral = "#FFFF7F50";
    public const string CornflowerBlue = "#FF6495ED";
    public const string Cornsilk = "#FFFFF8DC";
    public const string Crimson = "#FFDC143C";
    public const string Cyan = "#FF00FFFF";
    public const string DarkBlue = "#FF00008B";
    public const string DarkCyan = "#FF008B8B";
    public const string DarkGoldenrod = "#FFB8860B";
    public const string DarkGray = "#FFA9A9A9";
    public const string DarkGreen = "#FF006400";
    public const string DarkKhaki = "#FFBDB76B";
    public const string DarkMagenta = "#FF8B008B";
    public const string DarkOliveGreen = "#FF556B2F";
    public const string DarkOrange = "#FFFF8C00";
    public const string DarkOrchid = "#FF9932CC";
    public const string DarkRed = "#FF8B0000";
    public const string DarkSalmon = "#FFE9967A";
    public const string DarkSeaGreen = "#FF8FBC8F";
    public const string DarkSlateBlue = "#FF483D8B";
    public const string DarkSlateGray = "#FF2F4F4F";
    public const string DarkTurquoise = "#FF00CED1";
    public const string DarkViolet = "#FF9400D3";
    public const string DeepPink = "#FFFF1493";
    public const string DeepSkyBlue = "#FF00BFFF";
    public const string DimGray = "#FF696969";
    public const string DodgerBlue = "#FF1E90FF";
    public const string Firebrick = "#FFB22222";
    public const string FloralWhite = "#FFFFFAF0";
    public const string ForestGreen = "#FF228B22";
    public const string Fuchsia = "#FFFF00FF";
    public const string Gainsboro = "#FFDCDCDC";
    public const string GhostWhite = "#FFF8F8FF";
    public const string Gold = "#FFFFD700";
    public const string Goldenrod = "#FFDAA520";
    public const string Gray = "#FF808080";
    public const string Green = "#FF008000";
    public const string GreenYellow = "#FFADFF2F";
    public const string Honeydew = "#FFF0FFF0";
    public const string HotPink = "#FFFF69B4";
    public const string IndianRed = "#FFCD5C5C";
    public const string Indigo = "#FF4B0082";
    public const string Ivory = "#FFFFFFF0";
    public const string Khaki = "#FFF0E68C";
    public const string Lavender = "#FFE6E6FA";
    public const string LavenderBlush = "#FFFFF0F5";
    public const string LawnGreen = "#FF7CFC00";
    public const string LemonChiffon = "#FFFFFACD";
    public const string LightBlue = "#FFADD8E6";
    public const string LightCoral = "#FFF08080";
    public const string LightCyan = "#FFE0FFFF";
    public const string LightGoldenrodYellow = "#FFFAFAD2";
    public const string LightGray = "#FFD3D3D3";
    public const string LightGreen = "#FF90EE90";
    public const string LightPink = "#FFFFB6C1";
    public const string LightSalmon = "#FFFFA07A";
    public const string LightSeaGreen = "#FF20B2AA";
    public const string LightSkyBlue = "#FF87CEFA";
    public const string LightSlateGray = "#FF778899";
    public const string LightSteelBlue = "#FFB0C4DE";
    public const string LightYellow = "#FFFFFFE0";
    public const string Lime = "#FF00FF00";
    public const string LimeGreen = "#FF32CD32";
    public const string Linen = "#FFFAF0E6";
    public const string Magenta = "#FFFF00FF";
    public const string Maroon = "#FF800000";
    public const string MediumAquamarine = "#FF66CDAA";
    public const string MediumBlue = "#FF0000CD";
    public const string MediumOrchid = "#FFBA55D3";
    public const string MediumPurple = "#FF9370DB";
    public const string MediumSeaGreen = "#FF3CB371";
    public const string MediumSlateBlue = "#FF7B68EE";
    public const string MediumSpringGreen = "#FF00FA9A";
    public const string MediumTurquoise = "#FF48D1CC";
    public const string MediumVioletRed = "#FFC71585";
    public const string MidnightBlue = "#FF191970";
    public const string MintCream = "#FFF5FFFA";
    public const string MistyRose = "#FFFFE4E1";
    public const string Moccasin = "#FFFFE4B5";
    public const string NavajoWhite = "#FFFFDEAD";
    public const string Navy = "#FF000080";
    public const string OldLace = "#FFFDF5E6";
    public const string Olive = "#FF808000";
    public const string OliveDrab = "#FF6B8E23";
    public const string Orange = "#FFFFA500";
    public const string OrangeRed = "#FFFF4500";
    public const string Orchid = "#FFDA70D6";
    public const string PaleGoldenrod = "#FFEEE8AA";
    public const string PaleGreen = "#FF98FB98";
    public const string PaleTurquoise = "#FFAFEEEE";
    public const string PaleVioletRed = "#FFDB7093";
    public const string PapayaWhip = "#FFFFEFD5";
    public const string PeachPuff = "#FFFFDAB9";
    public const string Peru = "#FFCD853F";
    public const string Pink = "#FFFFC0CB";
    public const string Plum = "#FFDDA0DD";
    public const string PowderBlue = "#FFB0E0E6";
    public const string Purple = "#FF800080";
    public const string Red = "#FFFF0000";
    public const string RosyBrown = "#FFBC8F8F";
    public const string RoyalBlue = "#FF4169E1";
    public const string SaddleBrown = "#FF8B4513";
    public const string Salmon = "#FFFA8072";
    public const string SandyBrown = "#FFF4A460";
    public const string SeaGreen = "#FF2E8B57";
    public const string SeaShell = "#FFFFF5EE";
    public const string Sienna = "#FFA0522D";
    public const string Silver = "#FFC0C0C0";
    public const string SkyBlue = "#FF87CEEB";
    public const string SlateBlue = "#FF6A5ACD";
    public const string SlateGray = "#FF708090";
    public const string Snow = "#FFFFFAFA";
    public const string SpringGreen = "#FF00FF7F";
    public const string SteelBlue = "#FF4682B4";
    public const string Tan = "#FFD2B48C";
    public const string Teal = "#FF008080";
    public const string Thistle = "#FFD8BFD8";
    public const string Tomato = "#FFFF6347";
    public const string Transparent = "#00FFFFFF";
    public const string Turquoise = "#FF40E0D0";
    public const string Violet = "#FFEE82EE";
    public const string Wheat = "#FFF5DEB3";
    public const string White = "#FFFFFFFF";
    public const string WhiteSmoke = "#FFF5F5F5";
    public const string Yellow = "#FFFFFF00";
    public const string YellowGreen = "#FF9ACD32";

    public static string GetColorName(string hex)
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Colors).GetFields();
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
            if (field.GetValue(typeof(Colors)).ToString() == hex)
            {
                // corresponding color found -> return its name
                return field.Name;
            }
        }

        // no corresponding color found -> return null
        return null;
    }
}
```

If you are using C# 7.2, you could also make the struct readonly, which would look like:

```
public readonly struct Colors {

    public string AliceBlue = "#FFF0F8FF";
    // and so on ...
}
```

Instead of using a `struct` with constant fields, you could also use a `class` with static fields:

```
public class Colors {

    public static string AliceBlue = "#FFF0F8FF";
    // and so on ...
}
```

**Usage**

To get the value of a color or vice versa, you would do this:

```
// get hex value of color
string hex = Colors.AliceBlue;

// get name by hex color (using reflection)
string colorName = Colors.GetColorName("#FF00008B"); // returns "DarkBlue"
```

Comment: You didn't provide an implementation of GetColorName?

Comment: I did. Just scroll down a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know of is to make a lookup table of [known HTML colors browsers support](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp) and perform the lookup. Dictionaries are thread safe for read only operations so you do not need to lock on access.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class ColorUtils
{   
    private static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> ColorMapping = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["#F0F8FF"] = "AliceBlue",
        ["#FAEBD7"] = "AntiqueWhite",
        //... the other 136 colors
        ["#FFFF00"] = "Yellow",
        ["#9ACD32"] = "YellowGreen" 
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the color name or null if the name is not found.
    /// </summary>
    public static string ToColorName(string htmlColor)
    {
        ColorMapping.TryGetValue(htmlColor, out var name);
        return name;
    }

}
```