# How do I write this Hex Gradient in Codebehind?

Tags: c#, xaml

I trying to get the same color gradient in C# code

```
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF4557BA" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
```

So far I have this but it is wrong(can't find how to enter in Hex so I tried argb)

```
  LinearGradientBrush gradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
    gradient.StartPoint = new Point( 0, 0 );
    gradient.EndPoint = new Point( 1, 1 );

    GradientStop color1 = new GradientStop();
    color1.Color = Colors.Black;
    color1.Offset = 0;
    gradient.GradientStops.Add(color1);

    GradientStop color2 = new GradientStop();
    color2.Color = Color.FromArgb(100,69,87,186);
    color2.Offset = 1;
    gradient.GradientStops.Add( color2 );
```

**Edit**

I am trying to do this in wp7 where I have this gradient in a property that I will bind to the "background" of my controls.

I however it just seems like I get a solid color and not the gradient.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Try this `Color.FromArgb(0xFF,0x45,0x57,0xBA);`

Comment: This question is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is what I got:

```
  LinearGradientBrush gradient = new LinearGradientBrush();
    gradient.StartPoint = new Point( 0.5, 0 );
    gradient.EndPoint = new Point( 0.5, 1 );

    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Black, 0));
    gradient.GradientStops.Add(new GradientStop(Color.FromArgb(100,69,87,186), 1));


    whatevercontrolyougot.Fill = gradient;
```

Works fine here.

A screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try like this
 Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");

by refering 
using System.Windows.Media;
```

Comment: I am using Wp7 and it does not seem to have ColorConverter even with that using statement.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that you are refereeing alpha channel as 100 in code and in xamal you have 0xFF==255

so use this line in code

```
Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x45, 0x57, 0xBA);
```

C# allows you to enter values in Decimal, Binary or Hex,

Comment: It seems to lose the gradient when I do this though. Just gives me a solid color.

Comment: I mean only change your line `Color.FromArgb()` to this one