# How to Work by Class Color in C# in this?

Tags: c#

I write a string that by format RGB and i want use this string for forcolor textbox?
I cut this string to 4 string that values are like(ff,00,12,ff)
in visual studio this code run but show error that

> values not current format

```
textbox.ForeColor=
               Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(a[0]),
                              Convert.ToInt32(a[1]),
                              Convert.ToInt32(a[2]),
                              Convert.ToInt32(a[3]));
```

please help me about this.

Answer (score 2):

Specify base `16`, like this:

```
Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(a[0], 16),
               Convert.ToInt32(a[1], 16),
               Convert.ToInt32(a[2], 16),
               Convert.ToInt32(a[3], 16));
```

`ff` is not a valid number is base `10`. `Convert.ToInt32` uses base `10` by default. I assume you have correct values in `a` array.

For example:

```
string[] a = {"ff", "00", "12", "ff"};

Color color = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(a[0], 16),
                             Convert.ToInt32(a[1], 16),
                             Convert.ToInt32(a[2], 16),
                             Convert.ToInt32(a[3], 16));

Console.WriteLine(color); //prints: Color [A=255, R=0, G=18, B=255]
```

a more simple way is to use an instance of [ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colorconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string colorHex = "#" + string.Join("", a);
var color = (Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(colorHex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your values are in hexademical, so before passing them to `FromArgb` that accepts only integers, you need to convert them to integers.

```
int colorR = int.Parse(hexValueOfRed, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to take a look to the `ColorConverter` class you can provide directly an argb string to it.

this can be useful:
[Another question about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)