# C# get good color for label

Tags: c#, windows, forms, colors, drawing

I am using a random color for the background in my Windows Forms application. Now I want to display a label.

The problem is that when the random color is white and the label is too, then the label is not visible.

How can I get a perfect color that is visible on my background color? (My background color is a random color from `System.Drawing.Color`.)

Comment: Maybe look at contrast: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426819/finding-out-if-a-hex-color-is-dark-or-light or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855884/determine-font-color-based-on-background-color/1855903#1855903

Comment: You need to construct a color with Color.FromArgb. The complement might work. But to be sure do use the getBrightness function and make sure to build a color with enough contrast so you won't end up with two middle-of the road colors. Or keep picking a random color until the difference in brightnes is greater than 0.5.

Comment: Can you give me a code snippet please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165107/how-do-i-invert-a-colour-color

Comment: `List<Color> colors = ((Color[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))).ToList();
Color c1 = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];
Color c2 = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];
while (Math.Abs(c1.GetBrightness() - c2.GetBrightness()) < 0.5f ) 
    c2 = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];` Or, to make it less crazy, pick either White or Black, depending on the GetBrightnes value

Comment: Edit your question. Do not post code in comments.

Comment: TaW please write a Answer that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are various ways to ensure a proper contrast.

**Option one** : I usually stick to keeping the text Black or White, depending on the brightness of back color.

[image]

To get the brightness one could simply go for the built-in function [Color.GetBrightness()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness(v=vs.110).aspx)

Unfortunately this is not really a good solution, as the result is not perceptually correct; to wit: Green and Yellow have the same values, which is obviously not what our eyes will perceive.

Instead this tiny function will help:

```
float getBrightness(Color c) 
{  return (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B *0.114f) / 256f; }
```

Now we can pick either Black or White:

```
Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.BackColor = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];
lbl.ForeColor = getBrightness(lbl.BackColor) < 0.55 ? Color.White : Color.Black;
```

The code uses a list of known colors:

```
List<Color> colors = ((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))).
                     Select(x => Color.FromKnownColor(x)).ToList();
```

---

**Option two** : If you want to get colors in the foreground you could pick it randomly and repeat until you get a decent contrast by comparing e.g.

```
while (Math.Abs(c1.GetBrightness() - c2.GetBrightness()) < 0.5f ) 
            c2 = colors[rnd.Next(colors.Count)];
```

Note that you must not push the epsilon value too high or else it won't find a suitable color. This happens when trying to find a color that is too far away from a medium brightness! You could add a counter and after a while pick simply black or white..

---

**Option three** : Yet another way would be to construct a color with [Color.FromArgb()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb(v=vs.110).aspx).

You could start by inverting each channel, which will give nice color contrasts; but if the color one is of medium brightness and/or saturation you would have to correct, maybe again by picking black or white..

---

Note: for the above image I have enumerated all [KnownColors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx), which already looks pretty random.

To add some order you may sort the list by color properties, e.g. by hue, then by brightness:

```
List<Color> allcolors = ((KnownColor[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
    .Select(x => Color.FromKnownColor(x))
    .OrderBy(x => x.GetHue()).ThenBy(x => getBrightness(x)).ToList();
```