# How to get a contrast color for a given color using contrast ratio?

Tags: c#, colors, background, foreground

I need to get the contrast color for a text foreground using the background color and contrast ratio between colors.

Example:
Background - Colors.Red
Contrast ratio -  7.0

With the above inputs, I need to calculate the foreground color.

Is there any formula available to get this?

Comment: Is there anything about _this question_ that specifically relates to C#? This seems like a general colour theory question.

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar, Yes this is related to color theory. As I needed to implement this logic in C#, used that tag too.

Comment: how is this a programming problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50541212/14171304