# How do I bind a CustomControl Property to the control itself?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, colors

This is a follow up question to the one I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678176/how-can-i-convert-the-values-of-three-sliders-into-a-color/29679544?noredirect=1#comment47496530_29679544) -

The control class has a dependency property -

```
private static readonly DependencyProperty
    _Color = DependencyProperty.Register( "Color", typeof( Color ), typeof( ColorDefiner ), new PropertyMetadata( Colors.Black ) );

public Color Color {
    get { return ( Color )this.GetValue( ColorDefiner._Color ); }
    set { this.SetValue( ColorDefiner._Color, value ); }
}
```

In the control XAML, how do I access that property so that I may bind it bi-directionaly to the controls sliders responsible for defining the color property?

## EDIT

This is the code for one of the sliders -

```
<Slider
    x:Name="sdrRed" Height="32" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Width="294" TickPlacement="Both"
    TickFrequency="0.01" Value="{Binding Color, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Me}">
</Slider>
```

`Me` is the name of the `UserControl`. My thinking is that the problem is because I am pointing to the `Color.ScR` and etc.

Rather than binding the Value of the Slider to the Color property, I think I need to bind the Color property to a MultiBinding using the Slider Value properties.

## EDIT

This to me feels like a place where I should implement MVVM - Can someone tell me how I might go about doing that here?

Comment: Just for clarity, is this a CustomControl or a UserControl you're working with?

Comment: UserControl - sorry;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you'd like to multi-bind the `ColorDefiner.Color` property to the sliders inside the `ColorDefiner` itself. In order to do it in XAML, you'll need to do it using a style (you'll also need to specify fully qualified property name due to the style's target type restriction):

```
<UserControl ...>
    <UserControl.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="local:ColorDefiner.Color">
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource colorConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="sdrAlpha" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding ElementName="sdrRed" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding ElementName="sdrGreen" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
                    <Binding ElementName="sdrBlue" Path="Value" Mode="TwoWay" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    <UserControl.Style>
    <!-- sliders -->
</UserControl>
```

This approach has a huge drawback though - if end user sets a style for the control or sets a custom biding on the `Color` property, the multi-binding will be lost. On the other hand, if end user sets custom content for the control the sliders will be gone. That's why in this scenario you should really consider using `CustomControl` together with a template instead of `UserControl` and combine the output color in code-behind.

Comment: Ah, yes. That makes more sense. @Will, Grx70's point about the potential for the binding to be lost is a good one.

Comment: Custom Control - okay; got it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well you have a userControl that has sliders inside.
That's how I do it in Xaml do the following.

```
<UserControl x:Name="MultiSlider">
...
<Slider Color="{Binding Color, ElementName="MultiSlider"}.../>
...
</UserControl>
```

and the same with other properties and with the other Sliders.

ADDED

In the User control you need to add 4 dependency properties:

```
public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Color), typeof(MySlider), new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Red));
```

And the rest of properties

```
public double RValue
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty RValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RValue", typeof(double), typeof(MySlider), new PropertyMetadata(0, ValueChanged));

    private static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentColor = (d as MySlider).Color;
        var newcolor = new Color() { R = (byte)e.NewValue, B = currentColor.B, G = currentColor.G };
        (d as MySlider).Color  = newcolor;
    }
```

And then for the Green and Blue, and be careful on the casting of the NewValue I do not know if the slider range goes up to 255.

Comment: @Will ^^ like that :)

Comment: This does not seem to work - I'm testing by using the custom control and binding a Label's Fill color to the controls Color property - Adjusting it does nothing to the label.

Comment: How you change the Color, with the slider? then add , Mode=TwoWay

Comment: The color is controlled in three parts by three sliders - one for the R, one for the G and one for the B. There is a multi-converter that is supposed to accept a value from the R, G and B sliders and return a solid color. I set mode equal to two way, and it did not work.

Comment: Ok now I understand, so the slider is not connected to the Color directly, you can do the following, look the edit answer in 1 min

Comment: I see - that... could work; it seems like a multiconverter multibinding is likely not the way to go. I will test this and see if it works; thank you.

Comment: @Will, not necessarily - if you want to work with your MultiBinding solution from your previous answer, I'll post the code as an answer. Give me a min.

Comment: I suggest setting the value via `DependencyObject.SetCurrentValue` because setting it via the setter (which calls `DependencyObject.SetValue`) will clear any existing binding on the `ColorProperty`.