# Xaml x:Double / String binding (xamarin, uwp, wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

How can i make like a this:

```
<Color x:FactoryMethod="FromRgb">
    <x:Arguments >
        <x:Double x:Key="{Binding Source={x:Reference SliderR}}"/>
        <x:Double x:Key="{Binding Source={x:Reference SliderG}}"/>
        <x:Double x:Key="{Binding Source={x:Reference SliderB}}"/>
    </x:Arguments>
</Color>
```

But i think that primitive type does nor support binding function.

Comment: Why you do not want to use IMultiValueConverter like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678176/how-can-i-convert-the-values-of-three-sliders-into-a-color

Comment: I'm afraid you've gone pretty far in the wrong direction.  You cannot set bindings on arguments, because the `Color` instance is only created once; you can't update a constructor argument after the fact.  Additionally, you can only set a `Binding` on a _dependency property_, which `x:Key` is not.  In fact, it's not a property at all; it's a special member used to specify a dictionary key, and you can only use it on elements that are children of a dictionary object (like a `ResourceDictionary`).  Check the link @macieqqq provided, as it will show you how to approach the problem correctly.

Comment: And what's the exactly application you are developing? UWP or WPF ?

Comment: Xamarin app. Sorry for x: The key, I just checked it and also know what that means. But can I completely abandon the code and how do I anchor the element's color to the 3 values of the Slider object? I know that I can make my own markup extension and this will work, but is it possible without it?