# How to get RGB values from 24-bit Hex (Without .NET Framework)

Tags: c#, colors, hex, rgb

I am doing some graphics in C# and I need to convert a 6-digit rgb hexadecimal such as 0xaabbcc (rr gg bb)  into 3 RGB values.  I don't want to use `Color`.  I am not developing for Windows so I don't want to use the `Microsoft.CSharp` library.  Even if there is some way around that I'm not very fond of the .NET framework due to all the fancy fluff, I prefer to make my own class libraries and such.

I was able to convert 3 RGB values into a single Hex number but I don't know how to do the opposite.

```
private static long MakeRgb(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
{
    return ((red*0x10000) + (green*0x100) + blue);   
}
```

There is my code for the original conversion.

Anyone know a good way to separate a 6 digit hex number into 3 separate bytes?

EDIT:

I am *not* using the .NET framework, *not* using Mono, and I do *not* have access to System.Drawing.Color.

This should not be marked as a duplicate because it has nothing to do with .NET.

Comment: What's wrong with using Color? It isn't in Microsoft.CSharp. It's in System.Drawing and is available in Mono.

Comment: @Cyber If you're not developing for Windows, I assume you're using Mono, which has `System.Drawing.Color` *and* `Microsoft.CSharp`. You don't have to avoid using them.

Comment: If you want to store them in a long, you could use bitmasking

Comment: In particular this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5800540/477420) shows conversion with just bit manipulation.

Comment: I am not using Mono.

Comment: I tried to make it extra clear that I'm not using .NET or System.Drawing and I wanted to do it the Old fashioned way.  @TwilightSun answered the question perfectly, thats what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old fashion way that'll work in most languages:

```
long color = 0xaabbcc;

byte red = (byte)((color >> 16) & 0xff);
byte green = (byte)((color >> 8) & 0xff);
byte blue = (byte)(color & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use bitmasking

```
private static long MakeRgb(byte red, byte green, byte blue)
{
    return ((red*0x10000) + (green*0x100) + blue);   
}

private static byte GetRed(long color)
{
    return (byte)((color & 0xFF0000) / 0x10000);
}

private static byte GetGreen(long color)
{
    return (byte)((color & 0x00FF00) / 0x100);
}

private static byte GetBlue(long color)
{
    return (byte)((color & 0x0000FF));
}

long color = MakeRgb(23, 24, 25);

byte red = GetRed(color);
byte green = GetGreen(color);
byte blue = GetBlue(color);
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `System.Drawing.Color` and `Microsoft.CSharp` are available on Mono (which I assume you're using if you're not using .NET)

In any case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33049460/how-to-get-rgb-values-from-24-bit-hex-without-net-framework/33049515#33049515) was already a good answer, but if you're really not going to use `System.Drawing.Color`, then you should probably write your own class.

```
class MyColorClass
{
     public byte Red { get; set; }
     public byte Green { get; set; }
     public byte Blue { get; set; }

     public MyColorClass(long color)
     {
         Red = (byte)((color >> 16) & 0xff);
         Green = (byte)((color >> 8) & 0xff);
         Blue = (byte)(color & 0xff);
     }

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return string.Format("R: {0} G: {1} B: {2}", Red, Green, Blue);
     }
 }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     long lcolor = MakeRgb(50, 100, 150);
     MyColorClass color = new MyColorClass(lcolor);
     Console.WriteLine(color);
 }
```