# Getting the color object from ColorDialog.color.name

Tags: winforms, colordialog, system.drawing.color

In my winforms application I have a ColorDialog control and when the user select a color, I save the Name of the color object. For a custom color value starts with FF ex: fffdfcc8 (This is a light yellow / cream color)

Some where later I want to get to the color object from the color name string, fffdfcc8 to a system.drawing.color object. How can I do this???

```
        Dim dlgColor As New ColorDialog()
        dlgColor.AllowFullOpen = True
        dlgColor.AnyColor = True
        If dlgColor.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            DgView.CurrentCell.Text = dlgColor.Color.Name 
        End If
```

How to create color object based on the name value in DgView.CurrentCell.Text

UPDATE2:
Adding # in front of the custom name value and using the `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & color)` does get the job done. Not sure what to do next since to me it was not that obvious...leave it up to the moderator to decide

UPDATE:
This is not a duplicate since the name value is not a hex value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Color from Hexadecimal color code using .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-to-get-color-from-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Comment: @Phiter Its not a duplicate since the value I have is not a hex value that starts with a #. I also don't have the convertor library available

Comment: Just add a hash

Comment: You can do this: `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("# " + color);`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Thanks that did it, I did try the html function but did not think of adding the #. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix # to the custom name and use it like this should work. As indicated in the comments and updates. Thanks to Phiter Fernandes for the help.

```
   Dim strColor = DgView.CurrentCell.Text
   System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" & strColor)
```