# Error with changing color

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, colordialog

I have the following code to change colors and store into the database... For some reason it only allows one color to be changed from the colorDialog...

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{                
    ColorDialog col = new ColorDialog();
    //col.ShowDialog();
    string color = col.Color.ToArgb().ToString("x");
    color = color.Substring(2, 6);
    color = "#" + color;
    con.Open();
    string sql2 = ("Update Employee SET PanelColor= '" + color + "' WHERE EID='" + 17002 + "' ");
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(color);
    panel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
}
```

[Step 1 green color was selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/moAm2.png)

[Step 2 Messagebox showing the color codes(for testing purpose)(wrong color code)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Iuqw.png)

[Step 3 it uploads the wrong color into the panel...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvO6f.png)

I am not sure what is wrong with this... Please advice me thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Comment: Is the green color selected from `colorDialog1`? Then just get `colorDialog1.Color`. Why to create another ColorDialog `col`?

Comment: @MethodMan it is not the problem with the conversion but i think the problem is it is selecting the default color

Comment: what is the datatype of the field holding color in the database.?

Comment: varchar(50) but the database does not affect this in this case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (colorDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{                

    string color = colorDialog1.Color.ToArgb().ToString("x");
    color = color.Substring(2, 6);
    color = "#" + color;
    con.Open();
    string sql2 = ("Update Employee SET PanelColor= '" + color + "' WHERE EID='" + 17002 + "' ");
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sql2, con);
    SqlDataReader dr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
    con.Close();
    MessageBox.Show(color);
    panel1.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(color);
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this works but after trying out skyoxZ suggestion it seem to work