# ColorPreview for Hex Color in C# in VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, colors

I am programming with C# in VisualStudio and I got Colors given in hex string format. fex. "#D8AE6D". I want to quickly preview the color, so I know what the code stands for. For HTML/CSS there are many solutions. But I found non for usual C# code.

Is there a tool or addon that is recommended or even a built in solution?

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net).

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I want to actually see the color from Hex, not converting it to another format

Comment: I see. Then what platform? WinForms, WPF, UWP?

Comment: Its in string Hex like in my question. Its the c# .net framework .. is there a marketplace addon for this or is there an inbuilt solution, since for html/css there is a possibility I think

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preview the color from hex, I suggest that you could make the color as the picturebox balckcolor.

Like the following:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#D8AE6D");
            pictureBox1.BackColor = color;
        }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate when I can call/use your solution? I am looking for an "DevelopmentTime"/"EditorTime"-Solution, not runtime.