# How to use hex colors in f#?

Tags: f#

Instead of using Color.Yellow; I want to use a hex color such as E7DB1D. 
I tried to look all over Microsoft documentation for it and can't find it, also can't find a answer anywhere else.

Comment: You can do it using same [API that are used in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net).

Comment: Did you find the COLOR struct https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netcore-3.1?  If so what do you you want to do that this doesn't support?