# Setting color through hexcode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am setting my textmeshpro's text color with RGBA values. I would like to set it instead with hex code. I have an array of hex color values. How do I set this in Unity?

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public TMP_Text textMeshPro;
public string[] colorListHex = { "#FF0000", "#754C24", "#5DA500"};

void Start(){
   textMeshPro.color = new Color32 (255, 0, 0, 255); //How do I set it to be colorListHex[0] instead of using rgba?
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Comment: @ConnorStoop hi sorry, but from Unity's side, i think it does not work.

Comment: check [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB.html). `ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGB`  returns a string Hexadecimal string representing the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Color colorFromHex;
ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(colorListHex[0], out colorFromHex);
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString.html

Comment: Can be done in a single line `ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(colorListHex[0], out var colorFromHex);` ;) and should always be used with `if` to check if it was actually able to parse or not