# get colors value from hex code in uwp using c#

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I convert solid color to color code in c#?

```
if (t == 2)
{
     x.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
}
```

I need to get value from color code like `#ffeeee` instead of color name.

I have tried :

```
abc.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#ffaacc"));
```

But I can't use `ColorConverter` is there is any other way?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the color from a hexadecimal color code using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109756/how-do-i-get-the-color-from-a-hexadecimal-color-code-using-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ColorConverter, but it retuns a System.Drawing.Color. The problem is that the SolidColorBrush constructor takes a Windows.UI.Color.

There is a very simple way to convert the color from System.Drawing to Windows.UI:

```
public static Windows.UI.Color GetColorFromHex(string hexaColor)
{
    //get the color as System.Drawing.Color
    var clr = (System.Drawing.Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(hexaColor);

    //convert it to Windows.UI.Color
    return Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(clr.A, clr.R, clr.G, clr.B);
}
```

Comment: how to call the statment

Comment: x.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(GetColorFromHex("#ff0000"));

Comment: it worked tq very much

Answer (score -1):

```
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff0008");

abc.Foreground = _color;
```

You can try this, it worked with me.

Comment: System.Drawing.ColorTranslator is part of the System.Drawing namespace which is Windows Forms and not present in WPF project, I don't know if this is the case